# Трансформировать String в Date для datePicker Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, mobile-development

Здравствуйте!
Имеется дата вида "dd-MM-YYYY hh:mm". Она записывается в БД в виде string. Я ее фетчу в переменную, после чего ее надо трансформировать обратно в date для последующего присвоения datePicker. Подскажите как, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let strTime = "11-07-2016 19:29"
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-YYYY hh:mm"
let date = formatter.dateFromString(strTime)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-YYYY hh:mm"

var dateString = dateFormatter.dateFromString(date)
```

Comment: Парни! Фигня какая-то! Делаю как сказали вы. По брекпоинтам все верно но в момент, когда let test2 = payingDate2.date(from: leaseDateVarR)! все время присваивается 12.25.2016!!! Причем время верное присваивается, а вот дата, нет! (((((((((((((

Comment: let date = "02-02-2017";
            let formatter = DateFormatter();
            formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-YYYY";
            let test2 = formatter.date(from: date) Мистика! test2 присваевается 25.12.2016!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Что за фигня?

Comment: Разобрался!!!!!